# Is the polynomial interpolation of infinite points unique?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Is there a rigorous proof of the uniqueness of the polynomial interpolation of an infinite set of points ? Otherwise is there a counterexample ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.  There is not, in general, a polynomial that takes specified values at infinitely many points.

Comment: A polynomial that is $0$ at infinitely many points is identically $0$.  So two polynomials that agree at infinitely many points must be the same.

Comment: I claim that any polynomial interpolates any set of points. You probably want the *best* interpolation. Now, define "best".

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no such polynomial!

Suppose we work over an infinite field $K$. There is no polynomial function $f:K \rightarrow K$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for any $x \neq 0$. Indeed, a nonzero polynomial function $f:K \rightarrow K$ of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the other answer, existence is not guaranteed. But if you *do* have a polynomial $f(x)$ that interpolates infinitely many given points, that polynomial is unique.

This fact follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra; if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials interpolating your points, then $f-g$ has infinitely many roots and so must be the zero polynomial.

Comment: From my knowlegde, the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) claims that "every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root"